# Cannot use if else with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I'm trying to use conditionals in dplyr functions in order to build a plot in shiny. I have the following tibble:

```
head(example)

# A tibble: 20 x 7
   producto med_corte1_semana genero        aspecto          calidad    calibre     anyo
   <chr>                <dbl> <chr>         <chr>            <chr>      <chr>      <dbl>
 1 Pepino                  NA Almería       Sin clasificar ~ Sin clasi~ Sin clasi~  2012
 2 Pimiento                NA California r~ rojo             Sin clasi~          M  2012
 3 Pimiento                NA California r~ rojo             Sin clasi~ Sin clasi~  2012
 4 Pimiento                NA California r~ rojo             Sin clasi~ Sin clasi~  2012
 5 Pimiento              1,12 California r~ rojo             Sin clasi~ Sin clasi~  2012
 6 Pimiento                NA California r~ rojo             Sin clasi~ Sin clasi~  2012
 7 Pimiento                NA California n~ naranja          Sin clasi~ Sin clasi~  2012
 8 Pimiento                NA California a~ amarillo         Sin clasi~          G  2012
 9 Pepino                1,20 Snack         Sin clasificar ~ Sin clasi~ Sin clasi~  2012
10 Pepino                  NA Almería       Sin clasificar ~ Sin clasi~ Sin clasi~  2012
11 Pimiento              1,22 Sweet-Bite n~ naranja                   E Sin clasi~  2012
12 Pimiento                NA Ramiro        Sin clasificar   Sin clasi~ Sin clasi~  2012
13 Pimiento              1,40 California r~ rojo                     II Sin clasi~  2012
14 Pimiento                NA California a~ amarillo         Sin clasi~          S  2012
15 Pepino                1,54 Almería       Sin clasificar ~ Sin clasi~ Sin clasi~  2012
16 Tomate                  NA Baby-Plum     Sin clasificar ~          I Sin clasi~  2012
17 Pimiento              1,37 Sweet-Bite r~ rojo                      I Sin clasi~  2012
18 Pimiento                NA Sweet-Bite n~ naranja          Sin clasi~ Sin clasi~  2012
19 Pimiento                NA Ramiro        Sin clasificar   Sin clasi~ Sin clasi~  2012
20 Pimiento              1,14 California r~ rojo             Sin clasi~ Sin clasi~  2012
```

In Shiny, I have 2 select inputs. The first input is for the product (producto), and its initial value is "Todos" (all). When the user choose a product (Pepino, Pimiento, Tomate...) he can see the second select input, and he has the possibility to choose a filter (genero, aspecto, calidad, calibre) to group by.
I'm trying to transform data as follows:

```
profitabilitySum <- function() {
      product <- input$sumProduct
      filter_choice <- input$sumFilter
      applied_filter <- names(filters[match(filter_choice, filters)])
      f_period <- input$sumPeriod[1]
      s_period <- input$sumPeriod[2]

      subdata <- agrodata %>%
        filter(!is.na(med_corte1_semana)) %>%
        {if(product != "Todos") filter(producto == product)} %>%
        filter(between(anyo, f_period, s_period)) %>%
        {if(product != "Todos") group_by(filtro = producto) else group_by(filtro = get(applied_filter))} %>%
        summarise(precio = mean(med_corte1_semana))  %>%
        mutate_if(is.numeric, round, roundDecimals)
    
      return(subdata)
      
    }
```

And first I get this error:

```
Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

If I comment the line

```
{if(product != "Todos") filter(producto == product)} %>%
```

It returns a different error:

```
Error in get: invalid first argument
```

The thing is, if I try to execute the same code without the conditionals, It works no matters what condition I choose...

Comment: try `filter(ifelse(product != "Todos", producto == product, TRUE))`. I think you should share your expected output and some more input data. It sounds that we can much optimize your code.

Comment: Hi Roman, thank you for the answer. I just edited the post and tried to add more information. I also tried the solution you exposed but now It returns the following error:

`Error: no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "logical"`

The first value of `product `(`input$sumProduct`) is "Todos". But it seems like tries to evaluate the else statement instead of if...

Answer (score 0):

You could try your conditional lines with this syntax :

```
filter(if (product != "Todos") producto == product)%>%
   group_by(filtro= if(product != "Todos") producto else get(applied_filter))
```